# Using SFINAE on non static data members?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, sfinae

I'm new to SFINAE and I'm trying to write a simple Vector template. What I'm trying to achieve is to enable the z member variable based on the dimensions set for the Vector.

I have tried to achieve this effect using the following code:

```
template<unsigned int DIMENSIONS>
class Vector {
    // The x and y variables (same as z)

    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<DIMENSIONS >= 3>::type>
    /// <summary>
    /// The z coordinate.
    /// </summary>
    Float& z;

    Vector() : x(values[0]), y(values[1]) {
    }

    // Other member functions and variables

    std::vector<float> values;
};

template <>
Vector<3>::Vector() : x(values[0]), y(values[1]), z(values[2]) {
}
```

This should enable the z variable when there are 3 or more dimensions. This makes the compiler complain with the following error:

```
'Vector<DIMENSIONS>::z': only static data member templates are allowed
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure how to use initialization lists with SFINAE in such a situation. Because if the dimensions are smaller than 3, z would not have to be initialized (since it wouldn't exist). So far I've used a specialized constructor for 3D vectors (see the code above).

But intelliisense still reports that `Members 'x', 'y', 'z' are not initialized in this constructor.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use SFINAE with variable members. Usually it's used with functions overload.

Comment: @MattiaF. Would it be possible to conditionally compile variable members any other way?

Comment: Why dont just use a `static_assert`

Comment: I don't think so. There are no methods to add or not a variable member without some preprocessor tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
struct no_z_var {};

struct z_var
{
    float z;
};

template<std::size_t n>
struct my_vector : std::conditional_t<( n >= 3 ), z_var, no_z_var>
{
    float x, y;
};

int main()
{
    my_vector<3> mv3;
    mv3.z = 3.4f;
    my_vector<2> mv2;
    mv2.z = 3.4f; // error; no 'z'
}
```

However, is this a good solution/design? I'm not so sure; it can get messy. It will most likely present other difficulties during the implementation...

Comment: Good design or not, I didn't even know this was possible. I learned something! So thanks anyway :)
This could be useful in other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't conditionally enable variables like that. Your best bet is just to provide multiple specializations of `Vector`:

```
template <>
struct Vector<2> {
    float x, y;

    Vector(std::vector<float> const& values)
    : x(values[0])
    , y(values[1])
    { }
};

template <>
struct Vector<3> {
    float x, y, z;

    Vector(std::vector<float> const& values)
    : x(values[0])
    , y(values[1])
    , z(values[2])
    { }
};

// etc.
```

Though it might be more straightforward to use an array instead:

```
template <size_t DIM>
struct Vector {
    std::array<float, DIM> values;

    Vector(std::vector<float> const& vs)
    : Vector(vs, std::make_index_sequence<DIM>{})
    { }

private:
    template <size_t... Is>
    Vector(std::vector<float> const& vs, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
    : values{{vs[Is]...}}
    { }
};
```

Comment: Hmm, so that's the only way? I've been trying to avoid specialization like this because it would require me to specialize all other member functions as well, and I'd prefer to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: @Qub1 Hard to have too many member functions when you have different numbers of member variables. That said, any common functionality you could put in a base class (which could be CRTP)

Comment: I was also trying to avoid CRTP since there would need to be different names for the base class and the actual vector class and that could cause some confusion among users of the class, but I think its the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inheritance.

```
template<int n>
struct VecBase;

template<>
struct VecBase<1> {
    float x;
};

template<>
struct VecBase<2> : VecBase<1> {
    float y;
};

template<>
struct VecBase<3> : VecBase<2> {
    float z;
};

template<>
struct VecBase<4> : VecBase<3> {
    float w;
};
```

And then define your vector class:

```
template<int n>
struct Vector : VecBase<n> {
    // operations
};
```

If you want to make n-dimentional operation, you can use `std::get` and `std::index_sequence`. Let's start by making overloads for `std::get`:

```
namespace std {

template<size_t I, int n, enable_if_t<(I == 0 && I < n), int> = 0>
float& get(VecBase<n>& vec) {
    return vec.x;
}

template<size_t I, int n, enable_if_t<(I == 1 && I < n), int> = 0>
float& get(VecBase<n>& vec) {
    return vec.y;
}

template<size_t I, int n, enable_if_t<(I == 2 && I < n), int> = 0>
float& get(VecBase<n>& vec) {
    return vec.z;
}

template<size_t I, int n, enable_if_t<(I == 3 && I < n), int> = 0>
float& get(VecBase<n>& vec) {
    return vec.w;
}

}
```

Note that you will have to implement them for const.

Then, you can implement your operations by making a base class that implement operations:

```
template<int, typename>
struct VecOps;

template<int n, std::size_t... S>
struct VecOps<n, std::index_sequence<S...>> : VecBase<n> {
    float dotp(Vector<n>& vec) const {
        // Where sum is adding each parameter variadically.
        return sum((std::get<S>(*this) * std::get<S>(vec))...);
    }
};
```

And finally, make `Vector` extending `VecOps`:

```
template<int n>
struct Vector : VecOps<n, std::make_index_sequence<n>> {};
```

Note that I don't have a compiler at my disposition for the moment. If your got compiler error, just leave a comment and I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Specialize the entrie class for 1, 2, 3 dimensions if you want this, i.e., `template<> class Vector<3> { ... }`.

Comment: I've been trying to avoid full specialization, hence the reason I'm using SFINAE. Surely there must be another way?

Comment: Such a way is described in my answer.

Comment: @Qub1: for member fields it won't work; however, you're free to choose what you specialize. I'd opt for a base class with two or three fields. That said, your member functions will also differ quite much for 2 / 3 dimensions, so you need to specialize anyways, don't you?

Comment: @lorro Well yes, I would, however functions such as the dot product and operator overloads are pretty much the same for all dimensions (I just loop over the values array) and I hoped it would be possible to avoid repeating those in the specialized templates.

Comment: @Qub1: and how are you planning to loop over the values array, when the fields are named? That's what I'm talking about: you're better off having an `array<>`, perhaps getter functions `x()`, `y()`, `z()`, the latter enabled only for >=2 and >=3 dimensions using `enable_if`. Having named fields essentially disable you in using the genericity of the functions you mentioned.

Comment: @lorro yes, I think I'll settle on getter functions, as they are probably the closest I'll get to what I had in mind. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need SFINAE here. Just use specialization:

```
template<unsigned int DIMENSIONS>
class Vector {
  template<int I>
  struct ZContainer {};
  template<> struct ZContainer<3> {
    float z;
  };
  ZContainer<DIMENSIONS> possibleZ;
};
```

This has the advantage that you don't need additional templates. You can just add functions to the ZContainers for your class behavior.

Comment: And then you start allocating at least an extra byte even if ZContainer is empty...

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that. Thanks for making me look it up! That's what I like about StackOverflow: You always learn something, even by writing answers.

Comment: Note that your solution is *almost* perfect: I'd just suggest to put the contained elements (i.e., `float x, y;` or `float x, y, z;`) to a base class. (Why the extra byte: ZContainer<2>[100] has 100 elements, C++ guarantees that, when you take the addresses of two distinct objects, you get different values, hence it must be 100*alignment at least).